# Where can I find Numpy's astype() function definition?

Tags: python, numpy

I stumbled across this piece of code:

```
np.array([1,2,None]).astype(float)
```

Which produces:

```
array([ 1.,  2., nan])
```

I wanted to look at how this code converts None to nan. So I searched for astype function definition in Numpy's GitHub repository. Could you please help me find the part where it shows the code used to convert None to nan? I don't have enough python knowledge to understand how libraries like Numpy does things. After looking at their code I feel I don't know much about python.

All I can find from it is this in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/lib/user_array.py#L240:

```
def astype(self, typecode):
        ""
        return self._rc(self.array.astype(typecode))
```

I have no idea how Numpy uses this function. I could not find any other occurrence of astype function definition in the entire repository.

Comment: It's implemented in C. I think it's in [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/convert_datatype.c) but I can't read C well enough to follow exactly what's going on

Comment: There's also some more [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/278f85f12a8b2e904d7734e070f947ab4ccd16b6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to trace the action of the compiled numpy code.  Even if you can find the `astype` method, you'll probably have to dig several layers down to see you want.  The top method probably focuses on interpreting the parameters, while the conversion itself might take place in an entirely different section of code.

Note that your array is `object` dtype, precisely because of that `None` object.  The other elements are integers,

```
In [48]: np.array([1,2,None])
Out[48]: array([1, 2, None], dtype=object)
```

If I tell it to make an `int` dtype array, it raise an error:

```
In [49]: np.array([1,2,None],int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-c65114b3ba97> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([1,2,None],int)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

This is the same error that I'd get with `int(None)`.

Specifying `float` dtype, I get the `nan` as you do.  In effect this `np.array` call is the same as your `astype` method.  (See what I mean about it being hard to pinpoint where the 'conversion' is being done?)

```
In [50]: np.array([1,2,None],float)
Out[50]: array([ 1.,  2., nan])
```

Now `float(None)` raises a similar error, so the `numpy` handling on `None` is different from Python's.

`numpy` also converts the string 'nan' to float `nan`:

```
In [56]: np.array([1,2,'nan'],float)
Out[56]: array([ 1.,  2., nan])
```

It's not surprising that `None` is converted to a float `nan`.  After all, it stands for `not a number`.  But it will be quite hard to find the exact place (or places) in the `numpy` code where that equivalence is made.